# SciPy zeta function returns wildly large value

Tags: python, scipy

SciPy docs on the [zeta function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.zeta.html) states:

> y=zeta(x,q) returns the Riemann zeta function of two arguments:
>   sum((k+q)**(-x),k=0..inf)

Giving the parameters `x=2, q=0` we should get `sum((k)**(-2),k=0..inf)` which according to the [wiki entry on Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Specific_values) should give approximately 1.645

Yet SciPy gives the following

```
>>> from scipy.special import zeta
>>> zeta(2,0)
1.7976931348623157e+308
```

Am I missing something or is scipy zeta function broken?

Comment: notice the summation on the scipy page starting from 0, not 1 as it usually is defined

Comment: That may explain why it results in double max, I'll look into the source code

Comment: check the updated answer. I'm ready to bet 25 to 1 it's just that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The old docstring for [scipy.special.zeta](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.zeta.html) said:

```
y=zeta(x,q) returns the Riemann zeta function of two arguments:
sum((k+q)**(-x),k=0..inf)
```

According to the article in wikipedia, this is the Hurwitz zeta function, "which coincides with the Riemann zeta function when *q = 1*" (not q=0).  And indeed it does:

```
In [3]: zeta(1.5, 1)
Out[3]: 2.6123753486854882

In [4]: zeta(2, 1)
Out[4]: 1.6449340668482266

In [5]: zeta(3, 1)
Out[5]: 1.202056903159594

In [6]: zeta(4,1)
Out[6]: 1.0823232337111381

In [7]: np.pi**4 / 90
Out[7]: 1.082323233711138
```

*Update*: The docstring now explicitly says "The two-argument version is the Hurwitz zeta function" and "Riemann zeta function corresponds to q = 1."

Comment: I ended up realising this this morning, thanks for writing this up into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import numpy as np

def mzeta(x,q,N=100):
  s=0
  for j in np.arange(1,N):
    s+= 1./(1.*j+1.*q)**x
  return s


for N in [100, 500, 1000, 5000, 15000]:
  print mzeta(2.,0.,N), np.pi**2/ 6
```

produces

```
br@ratatoskr:~/sweethome/temp$ ./mzeta.py 
1.63488390018 1.64493406685
1.64293206551 1.64493406685
1.64393356668 1.64493406685
1.64473404685 1.64493406685
1.64486739796 1.64493406685
```

Notice that the summation here starts from `1`

UPD: Indeed, it seems to be the `j=0` value at the sum:

```
print "*****"
x, q=2, 0.1
print mzeta(x,q,10000) + 1./q**x, zeta(x,q)
```

which gives

```
*****
101.433199147 101.433299151
```

Comment: Thank you for your keen observation.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your post, but I figure I'd ask you before posting a question already resolved here: the zeta function takes complex numbers as arguments. It seems from everything said that the way to handle the `zeta` function in `scipy.special` is by just plugging a `1` for the second argument: `zeta(., 1)`, but how do you plugging in a complex number?